# Jackson 2.1.0 object serialize with JsonIgnore,JsonProperty and dynamic filter

Tags: json, jackson

I have an object which have several annotations:
`@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)` , @JsonIgnore`and`@JsonProperty("BLA BLA")`

I need to serialize my object while ignoring fields that their value is not changed, and also always ignore some other fields. while serializing I want some fields to have diffrent names inside the json String. all of that works great. my problem is when i try to filter out some fields dynamically! I tried every example I could find and nothing worked, I coukdn't exclude fields dynamically. mabye my other annotations are preventing me from doing that?

This is my code:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT) 
public class objectFilter implements Serializable {

@JsonIgnore 
private String filterDescription = "";

private String[] address = {"","0","false"};          

@JsonProperty("status.statusCode")
private String[] statusCode = {"","0","false"};      

@JsonIgnore 
private String statusCodeDescription = "";

@JsonProperty("createdUser.userCode")
private String[] createdUser = {"","0","true"};          
@JsonIgnore 
private String createdUserDescription = "";    

@JsonProperty("List.endorsment")
private String[] endorsment1 = {"","0","false"};      
@JsonProperty("endorsment")
private String[] endorsment2 = {"","0","false"};      
@JsonProperty("List.policy")
private String[] policy1 = {"","0","false"};      
@JsonProperty("policy")
private String[] policy2 = {"","0","false"};  

//getters and setters
}
```

I want to be able to exclusde some fields from being serialized even if they are not with @JsonIgnore
for example: I want exclude all fields except from policy2 and endorsment2 , even if the other fields have values inside of them.

How can this be done?

please help.

Answer (score 0):

So sometimes you only want to serialize `policy2` and `endorsement2` while other times you want to serialize all the fields? If so you can use Jackson's [JSON views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) to achieve this. You would first create a marker class for this view:

```
private interface OnlyPolicyTwoAndEndorsementTwo { }
```

And then you would set these two fields as belonging to this view:

```
..........
@JsonView(OnlyPolicyTwoAndEndorsementTwo.class)
@JsonProperty("endorsment")
private String[] endorsment2 = {"","0","false"};      
..........  
@JsonView(OnlyPolicyTwoAndEndorsementTwo.class)
@JsonProperty("policy")
private String[] policy2 = {"","0","false"};
```

And now to serialize the full object you could do:

```
mapper.writer().writeValueAsString(objectFilter);
```

Or to only serialize `policy2` and `endorsement2` you would do:

```
mapper.writerWithView(OnlyPolicyTwoAndEndorsementTwo.class).writeValueAsString(objectFilter);
```

Comment: I tried it but i still get other fields other then `endorsment2` and `policy2`.. mabye it's beacuse of `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Mixins: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations

Define that annotations of a mix-in class (or interface)
and it will be used with a target class (or interface) such that it appears
as if the target class had all annotations that the mix-in class has (for purposes of configuring serialization / deserialization)